# django-rest-swagger 2.2.0 endpoints with auth classes not visible

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I'm developing a django application that has a bunch of endpoints that have custom and basic auth classes defined, but swagger shows only endpoints that don't have authentication classes and have a permission class = AllowAny.

**How to make all endpoints be visible at 'docs/' endpoint without any authentications/permissions?**

`Django==2.1.7
djangorestframework==3.9.1
jango-rest-swagger==2.2.0`

`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    )
}`

`SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'exclude_namespaces': [],  # List URL namespaces to ignore
    'api_version': '',  # Specify your API's version. Might be useful in future
    'api_path': '/',  # Specify the path to your API not a root level
    'enabled_methods': [  # Specify which methods to enable in Swagger UI
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'patch',
        'delete'
    ],
    'token_type': 'Bearer',
    'api_key': {},  # An API key
    'is_authenticated': False,  # Set to True to enforce user authentication,
    'is_superuser': False,  # Set to True to enforce admin only access
}`

Comment: as a result I don't use `django-rest-swagger` and instead I switched to `drf-yasg` which is better to me and doesn't have such issues.